Using Clarabel as a backend of CVXPY
Is this a bug, or is there something fundamental I'm missing with how to use cvxpy?
Consider this code for a least squares optimisation for a 3 variable vector with 3 measurements:
import scipy
import numpy as np
import cvxpy as cvx
import clarabel

A = np.array([[-43.83695965,   0.34990409,  -1.32935518],
              [-48.86811152,   0.57411847,  -1.38219424],
              [-49.25621142,   0.75738835,  -1.2979702 ]])

b = np.array([  53897.91898074, -159390.11128713,  -62013.59835614])

bounds_arr = np.array([[-1., -1., -1.],
                       [ 1.,  1.,  1.]])

#------- Using CLARABEL as cvxpy backend---------------
x = cvx.Variable(A.shape[1])
cost = cvx.sum_squares(A @ x - b)

constraints = []
constraints += [xv >= bnd for (xv, bnd) in zip(x, bounds_arr[0])]
constraints += [xv <= bnd for (xv, bnd) in zip(x, bounds_arr[1])]
constraints += [x[0] + x[1] + x[2] >= -np.sqrt(3)] 
# constraints += [cvx.sum(x) >= -np.sqrt(3)] # This form doesn't work either

prob = cvx.Problem(cvx.Minimize(cost), constraints)
prob.solve(solver="CLARABEL", verbose=True) # Says 'PrimalInfeasible'
print("x: ", x.value)

#------- Using CLARABEL directly---------------
P = A.T @ A
P = scipy.sparse.triu(P).tocsc()
q = -b.T @ A
# Note constant term is ignored in this case because it is irrelevant to the solution of the optimisation problem.

Ac = scipy.sparse.vstack([-scipy.sparse.identity(A.shape[1]), 
                           scipy.sparse.identity(A.shape[1]), 
                           np.array([[-1.0, -1.0, -1.0]])]).tocsc()

bc = np.concat([-bounds_arr[0], bounds_arr[1], [np.sqrt(3)]], axis=0)

cones = [clarabel.NonnegativeConeT(A.shape[1]), clarabel.NonnegativeConeT(A.shape[1]), clarabel.NonnegativeConeT(1)]
settings = clarabel.DefaultSettings()
solver = clarabel.DefaultSolver(P, q, Ac, bc, cones, settings) #, A, b, cones, settings
solution = solver.solve() # WORKS
print("x: ", solution.x)

Most likely, I'm missing something fundamental with cvxpy - that is, why doesn't both approaches work?
If not, is this a bug in cvxpy?

It is a numerical issue. The coefficients of (Ax-b)^2 are so badly scaled that it is hard for the solvers to distinguish between optimal and dual infeasible. Divide both A and b by the same factor, say 1000. That will give you an equivalent problem (just rescaled the objective) and you will see it solves nicely.

By the way you could just write constraints += [x>=bounds_arr[0], x<=bounds_arr[1]] one of the points of such a tool is to nicely vectorize
